# The + + operator in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I have one plus, I get the wrong answer e.g.

```
var b = [069];
var total = 0;

total = total + b
console.log(total) // total = 069
```

However, when I add a second plus so the equation looks like this

```
total = total + + b  // total = 69
```

I get the correct answer of 69. The above is just a simplified example of my issue.

This works fine, however whilst using JSHint I get a warning saying

```
confusing pluses
```

How can I get the correct answer without using the + + ? Also, what is this operator called?

Comment: `[069]` is an **array**; you're initializing `b` to an array value, and then trying to use it with the `+` operator. What is it that you expect that to do?

Comment: Why not just `var b = 69;`?

Comment: `+` in front of a variable would cast it to a number if I'm correct. Try this in your console `"5"` would return `"5"`, where `+"5"` would return `5`. You could use `total = parseInt(total) + parseInt(b);` to get a correct result.

Comment: the spacing makes it look weird. It would be easier to read as `total + +b` (unary conversion)

Comment: `total + (+b)` = `parseFloat(total) + parseFloat(b)`

Comment: This seems to be perfect Answer material @AlexSzabó, go for it :)

Comment: Why are you adding an array to a number?

Comment: You can also get the same answer if you try with `total +- b`. You will not need the space between operators if you are are using the `+-`. You will need the space as `+ +` since `++` is considered to be an increment operator. Put a `+` or a `-` before a symbol to convert to an integer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Posting my comment as an answer

`+` in front of a variable would cast it to a number if I'm correct.

Try this in your console:

`"5"` would return `"5"` (string), where

`+"5"` would return `5` (number).

You could use `total = parseInt(total) + parseInt(b);` to get a correct result, as `parseInt()` would try to make a number out of any input parameter it gets.

Theoritecally, you could just parse the `total` as a number, but it would be prone to an error like `"1" + "0" = "10"` resulting in `10`, which should mathematically be `1`.

Answer (score 9):

Javascript unfortunately does a lot of implicit conversions... with your code

```
b + [69]
```

what happens is that `[69]` (an array containing the number `69`) is converted to a string, becoming `"69"`. This is then concatenated to `b` that also is converted in this case to a string `"0"`. Thus the result `"069"`.

If however you add another unary `+` in front of the array the string gets converted back to a number and you get a numeric result added to `b`.

```
0 + [69] → 0 + "69" → "0" + "69" → "069"
0 + + [69] → 0 + + "69" → 0 + 69 → 69
```

Exact rules are quite complex, but you can be productive with Javascript just considering the simplified form that for binary `+`:

- if both are numbers the result is numeric addition
- otherwise they're converted both to string and result is concatenation

One thing that is somewhat surprising is that implicit conversion of an array to a string is just the conversion of elements to string adding `","` between them as separator.

This means that the one-element array `[1]` is converted to `"1"`... and implies apparently crazy consequences like `[1] == 1`.

Comment: "unfortunately" You might want to de-bias your answer :P

Comment: This answer is way to advanced for the OP.

Comment: @EmileBergeron how advanced the answer has nothing to do with how skilled OP is. They asked a question, they got an answer.

Comment: @SterlingArcher I totally know that SO is not only for OP, I was just stating that this answer assume OP has way more knowledge of JS than what is shown in the question.

Comment: that is irrelevant.

Comment: Did you just assume OPs knowledge?

Comment: @EmileBergeron unfortunately that really doesn't matter. It's a very correct answer to OPs question. You can't reduce an answer, potentially making it wrong in order to cater to OP.

Comment: @SterlingArcher I did in fact upvote that answer, but it could start from where OP is and gradually get to where it is right now, helping everybody that comes across.

Comment: I don't think the answer is  allowed to be long enough to cover the distance between adding numbers to implicit conversions and unary conversions.

Comment: `[1] == 1` indeed, but not `[1] === 1`. Two equal signs can return true for `"1" == 1` it requires three `=` to check the type of the variable.

Comment: @SterlingArcher that's why I only commented. Is my comment only asserting a truth? Yes and that's it!

Comment: By that logic, your comment isn't constructive. OPs knowledge is non-constructive to the answer.

Comment: @SterlingArcher It's just an incentive for the author to take that into account.